# How to conenct in Visual Studio to the BDC from External List

Tags: development, bdc-model

I how got a question. How to connect to the External List with Visual Studio, and edit them BDC definitions in BDC Explorer Window. I try to open them, but I don't seethe BDC Explorer Window.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to create a Business Data Connectivity service using Visual Studio and SQL Server, If thats the case then you can follow [this MSDN tutorial.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hung123/creating-business-data-connectivity-service-using-visual-studio-2010/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello TimeToShine. But if i have got a External Lists should I Create a Business Data Conectiviti. Sametimes I could read from this ExternalLists, and somethimes don't. How to conect to External List from server ?

Comment: Try this link, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/10/bcs-and-external-list-learning-part1.aspx